# Hold down and release right-click with a single click

Tags: automation, mouse

Essentially, what I want to do is:

- Upon clicking the right mouse button, simulate holding down the right mouse button.
- Upon clicking the right mouse button once again, simulate releasing the right mouse button.

Use case: I'm playing an old first-person shooter with a Magic Mouse 2, so I can't aim and shoot at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of the two "go-to" apps for mouse control support the Magic Mouse. [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) or [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Magic Mouse 2. Do these apps work?

Comment: Did you check the links?

Comment: The latest version of USB Overdrive doesn't seem to detect the mouse.

Comment: it's right there on the link I posted... "Apple Magic Mouse 2, Magic Trackpad 2 and Magic Keyboard: Supporting Apple's Magic devices would disable their built-in functionality. I am therefore no longer handling any Apple device in the USB Overdrive, so you can use their original macOS multitouch gestures without any interference."

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/). Simply create this chain: [image: Right mouse button -> Toggle -> Right Button: Down / Up]

Comment: Yes, ControllerMate is excellent software, although it is more involved and does take some learning. I usually recommend others (such as USB Overdrive), but when these can't do the job ControllerMate is certainly worth a try!